# Update the view of a two dimensional array in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'am trying to update the view of a two dimentional array but the view nerver updates the new values.
If I only have one array it works fine but not with two.

```
export class App {

    constructor(){
        this.numbers = [];
    };

    update(){
        for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
            this.numbers[i] = [];
            for(var p=0; p < 4; p++){
                this.numbers[i].push(Math.random());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you post your view code too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing indexed assignment (`myArray[x] = something`) would require dirty checking. Use `myArray.splice(x, 0, something)` instead.

Here's an example using your view-model: https://gist.run?id=59e61de3899ded4225b54f44ac63ef8c

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div repeat.for="y of numbers">
    <span repeat.for="x of y">${x}, </span>
  </div>
  <button click.delegate="update()">Update</button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  constructor(){
    this.numbers = [];
  }

  update(){
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
     this.numbers.splice(i, 0, []);
      for(var p=0; p < 4; p++){
        this.numbers[i].push(Math.random());
      }
    }
  }
}
```